# Add css class in tr under condition

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have a table

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <table id="mytable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item ID</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Item Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Item 1</td>
                <td>$99</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Item 2</td>
                <td>$200</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to peform a check, if the value of the column item price is under 100 add `class="warning` in the tr.

```
<tr class="warning">
 <td>1</td>
 <td>Item 1</td>
 <td>$99</td>
</tr>
```

How can I do this with jquery I don't know much about jquery and my [try](http://www.bootply.com/zO6K7ezNna) till now is unsuccessful.

```
$('#mytable tr/* how i check here <100*/ ').addClass('warning');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** here,

> **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** : For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded. ( Taken from http://api.jquery.com/filter/ )

```js
$('tbody tr').filter(function() {
  return $('td:eq(2)', this)
    // get 3rd column using :eq(), :nth-child , :last or :last-child
    .text()
    // get text content
    .substr(1) * 1 < 100;
  // get number value from string by avoiding $ and compare
  // if it includes , then use txt.replace(/[,$]/g,'')
  // use parseInt(txt,10) for converting to integer
}).addClass('warning');
```

```css
.warning {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table id="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Item ID</th>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Item 1</td>
          <td>$99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Item 2</td>
          <td>$200</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good place/time to use `filter`.  Can be a little confusing for a beginner, but if you get your head around it, it's very powerful and ideal for chaining (as in this example)

Comment: Thx for the explanation. It helped me to understand your code.

Comment: @Nat95 : glad to help :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan One more question. If in the 3rf column I don't have the dollar sign, only the number e.g 99 what I delete from  your code? this `.substr(1) * 1`? here the http://www.bootply.com/Eyacgnh1y0

Comment: @Nat95 : You can use `.replace(/[,$]/g,'')` instead

Comment: @Nat95 : You need to use `:eq(2)` , since index is starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a little bit of coding, rather than trying to find some obscure or custom selector:

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function() {
    var val = $("td", this)[2].text().substr(1) * 1;
    if (val < 100) 
        $(this).addClass("warning");
});
```

Personally, I'd make this more maintainable than rely on column ordering by adding a class (the name doesn't matter):

```
<tr> 
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Item 1</td>
  <td class='data-value'>$99</td>
</tr>
```

then:

```
$("#mytable tr").each(function() {
    var val = $("td.data-value", this).text().substr(1) * 1;
    if (val < 100) 
        $(this).addClass("warning");
});
```

**Edit:** Added the `.substr(1)` as `.text()` will give the value including "$" then `*1` to get it as a number.  You could instead use parse int and remember to set it to base 10.

Comment: as you have a dollar sign within this column, you need to remove it to recognice it as value. so do: var val = $("td", this)[2].text().replace("$","");

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

You also need regex to strip the currency from the number.

Then grab the closest TR and apply class.

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/g6uz2Lfx/

```
$('#mytable tr td:nth-child(3)').filter(function () {
    var amt = parseFloat($(this).text().replace(/[$,]+/g, ""));
    return (amt < 100);
}).closest('tr').addClass('warning');
```